# Hide UIButton in Custom UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, custom-cell

In my tableview, I have several different custom cells.  In one of them, it has a button.  This button brings up another view controller.  However, It is not needed until the tableview has fully loaded.  In cellForRowAtIndexPath I set up all my different custom cells.  I can uncomment [buttonCell.myButton setHidden:YES]; and it will hide my button.  See below.

```
else if (indexPath.section == 3)
{
    ButtonCell *buttonCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ButtonCell"];

    //[buttonCell.myButton setHidden:YES];
    cell = buttonCell;
}
    return cell;
```

However, I want to then unhide the button after the tableview loads.  I finish loading all my arrays in another method where I call reloadData.  In that method, I tried to unhide the button by doing this..

```
[ButtonCell.myButton setHidden:NO];
```

But the compiler gives me a warning that property myButton is not found in ButtonCell. Does anyone have any ideas how to go about unhiding my button.  What am I doing wrong, and what do I not get!  Thanks for all your help.

EDIT 1

My button cell class is...
.h
    #import

```
@interface ButtonCell : UITableViewCell

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *myButton;
- (IBAction)YDI:(id)sender;


@end
```

.m

```
#import "ButtonCell.h"
#import "AnotherWebViewController.h"

@implementation ButtonCell

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
    // Initialization code
}
return self;
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
[super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

// Configure the view for the selected state
}

- (IBAction)YDI:(id)sender
{

}

@end
```

EDIT 2

With everyone's help that answered (thank you all) I have gotten a bit further, but the button is not showing itself.  So I still hide the button in cellForRowAtIndexPath, that works as should.  Then in my method that I reload the data in I put the following code.

```
NSIndexPath *index = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:3];
ButtonCell *buttonCell = (ButtonCell *) [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:index];
[buttonCell.myButton setHidden:NO];
```

The ButtonCell with the button is always the fourth section (counting the first as 0) and it only has one row.  Any other help would be appreciated.  Almost there!

EDIT 3
Got it!  However, it was due to a comment that I was able to figure it out.  Thanks to @A-Live.  Although I do know how to get the cell in a method outside of cellForRowAtIndexPath thanks to ElJay.  So I am giving him the check since I learned something new which is why we post questions anyway.  So inside my method cellForRowAtIndexPath is where I hide/show the button.  I have a BOOL in my App called finished, it is originally set to true.  When the table view ends loading it is set to false.  So I just used this bool to show/hide the button.

```
else if (indexPath.section == 3)
{
    ButtonCell *buttonCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ButtonCell"];

    if (!_finished)
    {
        [buttonCell.myButton setHidden:YES];
    }else{
        [buttonCell.myButton setHidden:NO];
    }

    cell = buttonCell;
}
    return cell;
```

Once again this is only part of my cellForRowAtIndexPath method.  Thanks once again for all the help. I was surprised to see so many answers!  Thanks.

Comment: Is there a type ? I don't believe the code should compile.

Comment: show us the ButtonCell class .h

Comment: @LithuT.V, I have included the ButtonCell class.

Comment: @A-Live, the posted code is just a part of my cellForRowAtIndexPath method.

Comment: As you always hide the button at `cellForRowAtIndexPath` you'll naturally not see it, you need to show the button there as well.

Comment: @A-Live, WOW! That did it.  It makes sense now.  I have a BOOL that changes when the tableView is done loading.  So when that changes, I change my hidden property accordingly.  Thanks so much.  Can you post this as an answer?

Comment: Cool, feel free to post your own answer summarizing all the required changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`myButton` belongs to a cell. You will need to get an instance of that `UITableViewCell` and then you can unhide it, this assumes you want to modify the cell's objects outside of `cellForRowAtIndexPsth` or `willDisplayCell`.

Comment: How would I do this.  I tried to get an instance of the ButtonCell, but it did not work in the method I call reloadData.

Comment: You have to know the indexPath of the row you are wanting to update, then it is just a matter of something like this - ButtonCell *buttonCell = [self.myTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:nowIndex];

Comment: thanks. I will try this tonight and let you know how it goes.

Comment: the size of my table view changes so I never know how many rows I will end up with.  However, the Button cell is always last.  So I was able to substitute your nowIndex, with my last cell.  However, I get the error incompatible pointer types initializing 'ButtonCell *_strong' with an expression of type 'UITableViewCell*'. Any ideas?  Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Make the property publicaly accessible.

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIButton *myButton;
```

Then in cellForRowAtIndexpath

```
ButtonCell *buttonCell =(ButtonCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ButtonCell"];
```

Comment: I think I already did this.  Check out my .h file for the  ButtonCell class.  And I did put your second line in my cellForRowAtIndexPath method.

Comment: @Douglas did you include `(ButtonCell *)` to typecast

Comment: ., Yes I did, although I am not 100% sure why to do it!  Will post some more code later to show.  Thanks again for all your time.

Answer (score 1):

Mistake in uppercase maybe ?

```
[buttonCell.myButton setHidden:NO]; // Trying to access instance variable
```

Instead of :

```
[ButtonCell.myButton setHidden:NO]; // Trying to access class variable
```

Comment: I can't use lowercase buttonCell.  This was created in cellForRowAtIndexPath, and I want to hide the button in another method.

Answer (score 1):

In your code

```
[ButtonCell.myButton setHidden:NO];
```

You are trying to use the object class name instead of the object name.  You need to get the cell that contains your button

```
buttonCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
buttonCell.myButton.hidden = NO;
```

Comment: thanks for your time.  The cell that has my button is always the last cell.  I have figured out how to get this last cell, but am unsure how to use cellForRowAtIndexPath.  I followed ElJay's suggestion, but that didn't work, please have a look.  Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Actually the cell is the last cell in section 3.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a public accessor for that property in the header file of ButtonCell? Something like `@property (nonatomic, retain) UIButton *myButton;`
This is how I usually see such a compiler warning.

Comment: Check Lithu T.V's answer. What you missed is the cast to ButtonCell. Your myButton instance would just be regarded as a regular UITableViewCell without that cast.  Have to comment on my own answer because I do not have enough rep yet.